# Jquery .animate() method doesnt seem to work with css top property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Hey guys I am trying to create a menu that slides down from the top of the page after scrolling to a certain point and is fixed at the top of the browser. For some reason, the `jquery` animate function doesn't seem to be completely working, but if I add an `alert("hello")` right after the animate function, it works fine. Here is my function code:

```
function header()
{
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    var rect = main.getBoundingClientRect();
    var menu = document.getElementById("menuappear");

    var y = rect.top;

    if (y <= 5)
    {
        $("#menuappear").animate({top:"0px"}, 500);
    }

    else
    {
        $("#menuappear").animate({top:"-93px"}, 500);
    }
}
```

heres my html:

```
<body onscroll="header()">
...


<div id="menuappear">
    <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" /></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a onclick="scrolltop()">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">What We Do</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Join Our Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my `css`:

```
#menuappear{
    z-index: 1000000;
    position: fixed;
    top: -93px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #242424;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #49CBCD;
}
```

If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong, that would be great.
EDIT: it kinda works sometimes but is really unresponsive

Comment: _"doesn't seem to be completely working...it kinda works sometimes"_ - Can you explain more clearly what actually happens? And/or provide a demo at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Try adding  `$("#menuappear").stop();` before your animate

Comment: yeah sure @nnnnnn heres fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/the_warrier/jvhN3/1/. what actually happens is that it sometimes scrolls down from the top but sometimes doesnt and also it takes a much longer time to scroll down than i put in the code. it should take half a second but ends up starting like 2 seconds late and then taking the half a second for the animation

Comment: @ChaseRocker its a `div` right under the `<div class="header">`

Comment: oh never mind guys @bobthyasian 's solution worked. that fixed the problem completely thank you so much. could you explain what exactly the .stop() does to make it work better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If more than one animation method is called on the same element, the
later animations are placed in the effects queue for the element.
These animations will not begin until the first one completes. When
.stop() is called, the next animation in the queue begins immediately." **[- .stop() | jQuery API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)**

---

The way that you call the animation via `<body onscroll="header()">` calls `animate()` multiple times essentially building up the queue. That leads to a delayed effect or not working at all. Alternatively, instead of using `stop()` you could set the queue param to false on `animate()`. Like so: `$("#menuappear").animate({top:"-93px"}, {duration: 500, queue: false});`